# How to read every file in a Google Storage bucket from BigQuery and create one table for each file in the bucket?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, federated-queries, federated-table

I have a bucket that has 28 files and I would like to load them in different tables (one table per file in the bucket).

Each file in the bucket looks like this:

```
file_1_2020.csv
file_2_2020.csv
..
file_28_2020.csv
```

I would like that the table had the first 6 characters of the filename + _table(they are all csv with headers). For example, `file_1_table`.

I read in a blog that I could achieve this by creating a federated query that list all files in the bucket. Then I could loop through all names and create the tables I need. The thing is that all documentation I have read on GCP is about federating queries in Cloud SQL, so I don't really know how I can make BigQuery read my bucket.

How can I achieve this? It's not important if it is done with a federated query (but I would like to know, because it's always good to know and learn new things). Also, I would like to have the tables partitioned and clustered by datetime, which is the first column of each file (the schema of each file is `datetime:TIMESTAMP,col1:FLOAT,col2:FLOAT`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to achieve this:

**Step-1:** Create an external table to get list of files in storage bucket

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.mytable OPTIONS (format = 'CSV', uris = ['gs://bucket_name/*.csv']);
```

**Step-2:** Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to create tables dynamically

```
DECLARE FILE_LIST ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE TABLE_NAME STRING;
DECLARE I INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE CNT INT64 DEFAULT 0;
SET FILE_LIST = ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT _FILE_NAME as FILENAME FROM mydataset.mytable);
SET CNT = ARRAY_LENGTH(FILE_LIST);
WHILE I <= CNT 
DO
  SET TABLE_NAME = CONCAT(SUBSTR(REPLACE(SUBSTR(FILE_LIST[ORDINAL(i)], INSTR(FILE_LIST[ORDINAL(i)], '/', -1) + 1) ,'.csv', ''), 1, 6), '_table');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset." || TABLE_NAME || " OPTIONS (format = 'CSV', uris = ['" || FILE_LIST[ORDINAL(I)] || "'])";
  SET I = I + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The first step worked fine :). The second one, I got an error that says:

`Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.file_1_2020_table OPTIONS (format = 'CSV', uris = ['gs://bucket_name/file_1_2020.csv'])`, Syntax error: Expected keyword OPTIONS at [13:21]`

Plus, its getting the full name of the csv file, I just need the 6 first characters of the csv file. The real name of the file could be `file_1_with_a_very_long_name_2020.csv`. And also, the execution of the step 2 query got billed for 22.9 GB :(.

Comment: Something I might have pointed out, is that the sum of the size of all files is around 22.9 GB

Comment: Thank you. But why was that error? I haven't executed the query yet, since I want to avoid getting billed with that error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) a new Google Cloud product for this use case.

In a nutshell, Workflows allows you to connect services together, anything that has a public API. Integrate any Google Cloud API, SaaS API, or private APIs.

Essentially you need to connect Cloud Storage with BigQuery to load the files.

[image]

You will need to have the following steps defined in Workflow:

- use Cloud Storage API to fetch files from your bucket/folder
- extract segments from filename eg: 12 and 2020 into variables for later use
- use BigQuery Load API to send the input sourceURIs obtained in first step combining segments from step 2 for your destination name format

There is a full blog post I have about this: [Using Cloud Workflows to load Cloud Storage files into BigQuery](https://medium.com/p/54228d166a7d)